# Extract information from Oracle dmp created with original Export

Tags: database, oracle, import, export

I have a DMP file which was exported with Oracle 10, with the legacy `exp` command ( not the `expdp` command ). 
However, I do not know what is inside.

For the import, I want to extract information from the file.

I know, that for `impdp` there would be options the extract information (like the contained users or schemas) from the export file. Is there a similar way to use `imp` to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IMP` with the `SHOW` parameter, such as

```
imp un/pw@db file=aldorado.dmp show=y
```

More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1019404)

> You can also display the contents of an export file without actually
>   performing an import. To do this, use the Import SHOW parameter.

Comment: Ok that worked out for me, when I leave out the "un/pw@db" and then enter the credentials "system" and "password" in the following prompt. So the SHOW parameter does a verbose dry run if i get it correctly?

Comment: I'd be surprised if "un/pw@db" worked :) These are credentials you should use, "**U**ser**N**ame / **P**ass**W**ord @ **D**ata**B**ase" , but your own. I thought - wrongly - that you'll understand those abbreviations & apologize; should have been more precise. Never mind, I'm glad you got information you were looking for.

Comment: :) No worries I understood very well what you were meaning. I just wanted to say that I left out that part and waited for the imp command to prompt for that information. Might be that your way works but I was not sure about the db name at that point.

Comment: Right; you can provide all that yourself, or wait for IMP to ask for it. The result should be the same.